# Distinguish et.al a. and et.al. b in natbib

Tags: natbib

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{A}
\author{B}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\cite{jia2019efficient}
\cite{jia2019towards}


 \bibliographystyle{chicagoa}
 \bibliography{Composite_reference}

\end{document}
```

The content of bib file is as follows:

```
@article{jia2019efficient,
 title={Efficient task-specific data valuation for nearest neighbor algorithms},
  author={Jia, Ruoxi and Dao, David and Wang, Boxin and Hubis, Frances Ann and Gurel, 
  Nezihe Merve and Li, Bo and Zhang, Ce and Spanos, Costas J and Song, Dawn},
 journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1908.08619},
  year={2019}
}


@inproceedings{jia2019towards,
 title={Towards efficient data valuation based on the shapley value},
  author={Jia, Ruoxi and Dao, David and Wang, Boxin and Hubis, Frances Ann and Hynes, 
Nick and G{\"u}rel, Nezihe Merve and Li, Bo and Zhang, Ce and Song, Dawn and Spanos, 
Costas J},
  booktitle={The 22nd International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and 
 Statistics},
  pages={1167--1176},
  year={2019},
  organization={PMLR}
}
```

But the generated document does not distinguish the two references.

Comment: First, I assume that you're aware that the `chicago` and `chicagoa` bib styles are quite old and thus do not represent the guidelines of the latest edition of "Chicago". Second, these bib styles are designed to be used not with `natbib` but with `chicago`. Yes, there really is a citation management package called `chicago`. Overall, if you do need to format the bibliographic entries and the citation call-outs according to the guidelines of the current edition of "Chicago", I can only suggest that you switch to `biblatex`/`biber`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comments. So when I use biblatex to execute the current edition of "Chicago", what style name shall I choose? I tried "\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chicago,
  ]{biblatex}", but it does not work.

Comment: Do give `\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}` a try.